# Why am I getting the error message, expected unqualified id before 'for'

Tags: c++

I have to write a code that does this for a university assignment. I have written the average function of the code but I'm getting an error message for the other function. 
The DEVBOARD_readAccelerometer function will read x,y,z components of acceleration

Firstly, you will need to write a function:
     int average(int *array, int nLen);
which returns the average value of an array of integer values. (To prevent overflow, it is suggested to use a long internal variable).
The Spirit Level function will run a loop. For each iteration the Z-component of gravitational acceleration will be sampled four times at 50ms intervals and stored in a suitably sized array.
Using the average() function you have written, determine the average value and analyze

```
int average(int* array, int nlen) {  // assuming array is int
  long sum = 0L;  // sum will be larger than an item, long for safety.
  for (int i = 0; i < nlen; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return ((long)sum) / nlen;
}

float sum[3];
int j;
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  i = DEVBOARD_readAccelerometer(int* xAccel, int* yAccel, int* zAccel);
  sum[j] = int * zAccel;
}
average(float* sum[j], float nlen);
printf("The average zcomponent is %f\n");
}
```

---

```
unqualified-id before for
```

Comment: Most of that code does not appear to exist in a function.

Comment: I formatted the code. Your typo stands out now.

Comment: I would say that maybe you have an extra `}` after `return` but then the rest would be dead code. This looks like a combination of mistakes that makes it hard to understand what the original intention was and thus figure out which mistakes were actually made.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code starting with `float sum[3];`? Is this supposed to be your `int main()`? Although if it is `average(float* sum[j], float nlen);` is not correct syntax. and the following line is a bug as well: `printf("The average zcomponent is %f\n");`  and also `i = DEVBOARD_readAccelerometer(int* xAccel, int* yAccel, int* zAccel);` and `sum[j] = int * zAccel;`

Answer (score -1):

You declared variable `j` 2 times. One *before* the for loop and one *inside* the for definition.

Comment: Almost every line after `float sum[3];` is a bug. Also it's unclear what this code is doing outside a function since that itself is a bug.